# Pagination for markdown files in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, pagination, markdown

I want to use pagination for a blog that renders the posts from markdown files via storage.

In controller method, I'm using the following:

```
        // Getting all files from the storage:
        $files = Storage::disk('articles')->allFiles();
        $articles = [];

        foreach ($files as $file) {
           $storageFile = Storage::disk('posts')->get($file);
           array_push($articles, $storageFile);
        }

        return view('articles', compact('files', 'articles'));
```

How can I obtain the same results as:

```
    $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->paginate(1);
```

I want to display one article (one file) per page.

Thanks!

Comment: `https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-6-paginate-with-collection-or-arrayexample.html` may help.

Comment: You'd most likely need to [Manually Create A Paginator](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#manually-creating-a-paginator)